# Get all records of Select action inside Do Until loop using logic app

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-logic-app-standard

There is a do-until loop that iterates 5 times until variable nextIteration = null.

Every iteration has 100 records i.e., 1 iteration = 100 records. Therefore, total records are 5*100 = 500

[image]

Now, I want to use above "Select from HTTP request" action inside a "For each" loop to iterate through each 500 records but, under "Select from HTTP request" action I only get last iteration's records i.e., only 100 records for 5th iteration.

I want to get all 500 records inside "Select from HTTP request" action from iteration 1 to iteration 5.

[image]

What is wrong in my approach and how can I achieve it?

I also tried putting "Select from HTTP request" action outside of do-until loop but it did not help.

I'm new to the Logic App or any other technologies with the same idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved it by adding a 'Set variable' with union() expression of Http request inside do-while.